# GUI Library for Ruby supporting Linux

Tags: open-source, library, programming, ruby, gui-builder

Minimal requirement is support for Linux.

The most important is that it is usable in production and open-source with decent documentation (so amount of bugs and problems will be low and once encountered fixing it will be possible).

I would prefer a cross-platform GUI library, with native look and feel.

It is necessary to support Linux, it is preferable to support also Windows and Mac. Supporting additional platform would be nice.

It is also strongly preferable that it would easy in use and do not require huge amount of boilerplate code.

Library in active development would be better.

question based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260905/whats-the-best-easiest-gui-library-for-ruby (it was closed there as offtopic, there are some answers).

Comment: Note that terms like "the best" and "the easiest" are pretty much subjective, and should preferably not be used in titles (to avoid flame-wars and low-quality link-only (or other one-line) answers – which is why I "cleaned up" your posts's title a little. Good hunting!

Comment: See [With what tools can I make a complex and advanced GUI with Ruby?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/53553/36725). The Mac-specific options there are obvious. Most of the listed toolkits are cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Qt is one of the most widely used cross-platform widget toolkits and there are also [bindings for Ruby](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Ruby). In case you use JRuby, you can use JavaFX. There's also [a wrapper library](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx) available.

Answer (score 0):

[Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/downloads/) I believe has a native look and feel I have only used it briefly on Windows but the screen shots on the website make it look native on the other platforms. I see this was already on the linked Stack Overflow question.  For what it is worth I'm mostly a back end programming and i found shoes was pretty easy to work with.