# With what tools can I make a complex and advanced GUI with Ruby?

Tags: gui, ruby

First of all (as a curiosity) please answer me something.

**Can PURE Ruby be used to make GUI without using other libraries or tools?**

---

Now let's get down to business.

I use Ruby 2.5.3 and because I have a project whose graphical interface is very complex, Qt doesn't work for me, the truth is I see it very limited and besides its license doesn't suit me.

The target OS is preferably Linux but if it works with other platforms there is no problem.

It doesn't matter if the tool to use is difficult, what matters to me is that:

*** Have official and complete documentation.**

*** That you have a very large number of widgets.**

I saw some gems that were easy to build GUI but very limited so I discarded them.

There is someone who told me that I should learn C and create the GUI with that language and combine it with Ruby, I have no problem with learning C but I don't see how I can combine the two, I've never mixed programming languages but what do you think? Is it possible to do it?

**Anyway for now more important is to work alone with Ruby.**

Comment: Discussing how Ruby and C can interact is a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

First, as far as "Pure Ruby", [RubyTk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_guide.htm) is packaged with MRI and doesn't usually require separate installation on Windows or Mac. However, we're talking about using a GUI toolkit, so of course some GUI toolkit library is being used beyond the core Ruby interpreter. Almost all of these libraries will require some prerequisite installation steps. However, you can access the library with Ruby; you don't need to write code in any other language.

In rough subjective order of their current suitability for writing complex GUIs:

1. [Ruby-Gnome2](http://ruby-gnome2.osdn.jp/) ([source](https://github.com/ruby-gnome/ruby-gnome)) using [GTK](https://www.gtk.org/) ([Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/rubygtk/))
2. [JRubyFX](https://github.com/jruby/jrubyfx) using [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)
3. [FXRuby](https://github.com/larskanis/fxruby) using [Fox Toolkit](http://fox-toolkit.org/)
4. [wxRuby](https://github.com/mcorino/wxRuby3) using [wxWidgets](https://wxwidgets.org/)
5. [Glimmer](https://github.com/AndyObtiva/glimmer)
6. [LibUI](https://dev.to/kojix2/libui-a-new-ruby-gui-library-that-is-easy-to-install-2d3c) ([source](https://github.com/kojix2/LibUI)) using [libui](https://github.com/andlabs/libui) and [libui-ng](https://github.com/libui-ng/libui-ng)
7. [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/) for iOS and Android
8. [RubyTk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_guide.htm) ([source](https://github.com/ruby/tk), [additional documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20201009085926/https://sites.google.com/site/gyakuhikiruby/home/gui/tk))
9. [ShenmeGUI](https://github.com/onyxblade/ShenmeGUI) - Similar to Shoes

You can compare GitHub statistics on these toolkits at *[The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/GUI_Frameworks?display=table&order=rubygem_downloads)*. Note that some toolkits are frequently installed via other mechanisms than RubyGems, and so will not accurately represented in Ruby Toolbox's downloads statistics.

A more thorough review as of 2018 is available from [Saverio Miroddi](https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/An-overview-of-ruby-gui-development-in-2018/).

If you're familiar with making web applications, then running a local server or [scripting a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11724201/5389585) with Selenium, Watir, or Win32OLE are very viable options, as described by [James Warren](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/infoworks-icm-guis-ruby-part-2-james-warren/). [Flammarion](https://github.com/zach-capalbo/flammarion) uses this technique in an awesome way for short and simple GUIs for scripts ([eg.](https://github.com/zach-capalbo/flammarion#message-composer-with-address-book)), but is not suitable for complex applications.

Note that Ruby can access a variety of lower level interfaces eg. Windows, .NET, FFI, Java, so there's really no GUI toolkit that can't be accessed somehow.

#### Dead but interesting options:

3. Ruby libraries using [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software))

   - [QtRuby](https://github.com/KDE/qtruby) ([documentation](https://techbase.kde.org/Languages/Ruby)) (Dead since 2013)
   - [Korundum](https://github.com/KDE/korundum) using [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE) (Dead since 2015)
   - [qtbindings](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings) (Dead since 2020, supports Qt4 up to 4.8.6)
   - [ruby-qml](http://seanchas116.github.io/ruby-qml/) using QML and Qt Quick (Dead since 2019)
   - [qt_connect](https://github.com/CeesZ/qt_connect) - Similar interface to Qt libraries through JRuby or through QtRuby (Dead since 2012)
4. [Fidgit](https://github.com/gosu/fidgit) - Similar to Shoes. (Dead since 2019)
5. [MacRuby](http://macruby.org/) ([source](https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby)) using Mac OS X (Dead since 2013)
6. [MonkeyBars](https://github.com/monkeybars/monkeybars-core) using JRuby and Swing (Dead since 2015)
7. [RubyCocoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyCocoa) ([source](https://github.com/rubycocoa/rubycocoa)) (Dead since 2017)
8. [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) ([source](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4)) (Dead since 2018)
9. [Opal-UI](https://github.com/ppibburr/opal-ui) using [Opal](https://opalrb.com/) to compile Ruby to Javascript and run it in a browser. (Dead since 2014)
10. Additional [Fox Toolkit](http://fox-toolkit.org/) libraries

    - [FXRuby Enhancement](https://github.com/flajann2/fxruby-enhancement) (Dead since 2017)
    - [foxGUIb](http://www.mikeparr.info/rubyguib/foxguibhome.htm) ([source](https://github.com/henon/foxguib), [secondary website](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/FoxGUIb)) (Dead since 2010)
11. [IronRuby](http://ironruby.net/) using .NET
12. [Anvil](https://github.com/lancecarlson/anvil) - MVC framework on top of other GUI toolkits. Dead since 2008.
13. [Bowline](https://github.com/maccman/bowline) (Dead since 2010)
14. [Limelight](https://github.com/slagyr/limelight) on JRuby
15. [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/) bindings built for MRuby were largely written but never released by [RyanScottLewis](https://github.com/RyanScottLewis/mruby-fltk) and [mattn](https://github.com/mattn/mruby-fltk3)
16. [Green Shoes](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes) (Dead since 2013)
17. [Visual Ruby](https://sourceforge.net/projects/visualruby/) (Dead since 2014)